# Why solution to fix png transparency issue of GD does not work?

Tags: php, png, transparency, php-gd

I have this code (simplified) on render png:

```
$this->image = imagecreatefrompng($this->file);
header("Content-Type: {$this->imageInfo['mime']}");
imagepng($this->image);
```

After I got black background, I was looked for some solutions, which didn't work. Easier one:

```
$this->image = imagecreatefrompng($this->file);
imagealphablending($targetImage, false);
imagesavealpha($targetImage, true);
header("Content-Type: {$this->imageInfo['mime']}");
imagepng($this->image);exit();
```

People claims that it works, but I still have black background, so I tried other one:

```
$this->image = imagecreatefrompng($this->file);
$targetImage = imagecreatetruecolor($this->imageInfo[0], $this->imageInfo[1]);
imagealphablending($targetImage, false);
$color = imagecolorallocatealpha($targetImage, 0, 0, 0, 127);
imagefill($targetImage, 0, 0, $color);
imagecolortransparent($targetImage, $color);
imagesavealpha($targetImage, true);
imagecopyresampled($targetImage, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $this->imageInfo[0], $this->imageInfo[1], $this->imageInfo[0], $this->imageInfo[1]);
header("Content-Type: {$this->imageInfo['mime']}");
imagepng($this->image);exit();
```

Result is the the same in all modern browsers. How it is possible, any idea?
Code is part of class which work with all types of images and all functions works correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you want to send the `png` file as is, so why convert it using GD first? I would just use [`readfile()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) and output the file:

```
header("Content-Type: {$this->imageInfo['mime']}");
readfile($this->file);
exit();
```

*For your other tests:*

You want to output `$targetImage` instead of `$this->image` at the end, otherwise nothing fancy will happen. Also I think you need to enable alpha blending before `imagecopyresampled` instead of disabling it, to avoid black borders.

```
$this->image = imagecreatefrompng($this->file);
$targetImage = imagecreatetruecolor($this->imageInfo[0], $this->imageInfo[1]);

$color = imagecolorallocatealpha($targetImage, 0, 0, 0, 127);
imagefill($targetImage, 0, 0, $color);
imagecolortransparent($targetImage, $color);
imagealphablending($targetImage, true);
imagecopyresampled($targetImage, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $this->imageInfo[0], $this->imageInfo[1], $this->imageInfo[0], $this->imageInfo[1]);
header("Content-Type: {$this->imageInfo['mime']}");
imagepng($targetImage);
exit();
```

Comment: Wow, you are right with first point, but I no need imagecopyresampled (it was just test). I need just display png by PHP (first part of code). Would you know how do it without imagecopyresampled? Thanks

Comment: then don't convert it to png and back, just send the file as is using `readfile`, see example #1 [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php)

Comment: I tried it (readfile), but I am still getting black picture instead transparent picture. That is strange, isn't it?

Comment: Then the png on disk is not transparent perhaps?

Comment: It is, there was some logical error, but your advice (readfile) really help me to find core of problem. Thanks